# How to morph a player character into another entity in MC JAVA 1.16-1.17?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I want to add morphs into my game. Is there any command/code/resource I can use to make someone morph into an entity?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. The StackExchange format does not support packing multiple questions into a single post. Posts that contain multiple questions can be placed on hold until they're focused to a single issue.

Comment: @DMGregory Alright...

Comment: Please remember to search on your search engine before coming here. There have been several tutorials created on this topic already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a mod for this found [here](https://www.kingminecraftmod.com/identity-mod/). Here is how to install the mod into your Minecraft client.

1. Download and Install **Fabric Installer** for Minecraft 1.16 found [here](https://fabricmc.net/).
2. Run Fabric's .jar file, choose the Minecraft version you want and press “Install.”
3. Next, run Minecraft, with the Fabric profile chosen.
4. Then, go into `/Appdata/Local/.minecraft/mods` and put the morph mod into the folder.
5. Finally, restart Minecraft in order for the mod to be imported.